# Encrypted string to Byte Array

Tags: php

I'm encrypting a string using this function;

```
$encrypted_body = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, utf8_encode($body), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 
//Encrypting using MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 algorithm
```

I then get my encrypted string.

What i need to do next is convert this string into a Byte Array. How do I do this? I've played with the pack/unpack features but am not having any luck!

Any help would be great.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not have byte arrays. What other languages call byte arrays are just a string of bytes one after the other, which can be accessed by their offset. PHP *strings* in fact do the same thing:

```
$encrypted_body[0]  ->  first byte
$encrypted_body[1]  ->  second byte
$encrypted_body[n]  ->  n+1th byte
```

So, just use PHP strings for the same purpose.